# Negative number fails JSON schema validation check in Visual Studio (with Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, jsonschema

As can be seen from the screenshot, a negative number is failing the JSON schema validation for a property of type "number". Why would this be?

[image]

The Visual Studio version is 15.5.4. Resharper version is 2017.3.2.

The relevant schema section is:

```
"threshold": {
  "type": [
     "number",
     "null"
  ],
  "minimum": -1.0,
  "maximum": 1.0
}
```

Comment: Sure sounds like a bug to me. If it's a bug with VS or Resharper, I don't know. Consider [filing a support request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) with MS VS.

Comment: I part of the team that works on JSON Schema. We've tried to reach out to the VSCode team to see if anyone is interested in driving or giving some directions to the spec, but haven't gotten anywhere =/

Comment: Thanks, yes it is strange that JSON Schema is not better supported.

Comment: @Relequestual if you ask the wrong people - this is a Resharper question and VS Code is *not* Visual Studio. VS Code is an open source project. You don't "reach out" to an open source project, you submit an issue or better yet, a PR on Github. Do you have a link to the issue so we can pester them a bit? Or even help?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was trying to be brief. I'm aware VSCode is not the same as Visual Studio, but both are Microsoft owned. By reach out I did mean submit a github issue. I'm not aware of any issues with VSCode, but we wanted to invite them to join in helping develop JSON Schema, as they rely on it for core functionality, but someone there didn't seem to understand what we were proposing: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23016

Comment: I didn't say I reached out to the VSCode team about this issue...

Comment: @Relequestual this is still a Resharper question. As for that issue - I see it took quite a while to explain what you wanted and then talked about "MS" in an *open source project". There are a lot of *contributors*, not just MS employees. Even they are there as individual contributors, not MS employees.

Comment: @Relequestual one could say that this issue is as misplaced as the comments in *this* question. I'd strongly suggest that you misunderstood the discussionand reach the wrong conclusion that somehow the VS Code maintainers don't want to work with the JSON Schema team

Comment: Sure, this question might be a Resharper question, but that wasn't certain, as I explained. It may have been a VS issue, in which case my comments would have been valid. "Even they are there as individual contributors, not MS employees" - What does it matter? MS employees still replied.

Comment: @Relequestual the conversation in that issue - good grief. It's actually *three* different conversations going on at once. No wonder nobody understood what the other was saying or asking. And it does matter that they are *contributors*, not MS employees. You are talking to individual people, not to "Microsoft" or any team in there. The initial posts were unclear, then the discussion was sidetracked, or rather split in two with one of them the JSON Schema maintainers talking about themselves. By September it wa unsalvageable

Comment: I think we are talking about different things here. It looks like we have different opinions on that issue. If you'd like to discuss further, let's move to a chat (either here, or you're welcome to join the json schema slack)

Comment: @Relequestual and like all long threads and discussions, the intenderd audience simply left the discussion. Just like *this* discussion here - bet our comments will be deleted very soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the known issue in [ReSharper bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466259)